# How does "minimize" work in Z3

Tags: optimization, z3, smt, theorem-proving, satisfiability

I'm using the minimize function in Z3 a lot and I'm worrying about some scalability issues (when the number of variables I'm minimizing grows). What is the underlying algorithm of "minimize" and is there a general way to speed things up?

Answer (score 1):

See this [paper](https://easychair.org/publications/open/200953) for details on the optimization algorithms used in Z3. Regarding your question about "general way to speed things up:" Impossible to tell without seeing exactly what you're trying to do and how you are encoding it. Posting a concrete example where things don't "scale" might be helpful.

Comment: My problem setup is simple: I'm working on satisfying the maximum number of multi-valued logical clauses C_1,...,C_m. I use bit-vectors.
For each clause C_i, I disjunct it with a fresh variable (bit-vector) b_i:
C_1 or b_1
C_2 or b_2
...
C_m or b_m

and I minimize b_i's:
(minimize b_1) (minimize b_2) ... (minimize b_m)

So my question is specifically about how minimizing bit-vectors works and if there are tricks to speed it up.

Comment: Sounds like you're solving max-sat? If that's the case, soft constraints is the way to go: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorialcontent/optimization#h23 The idea is that Z3 will try to satisfy as many of the soft-constraints as it can, while trying to keep the associated penalty to a minimum for those it cannot satisfy.

Comment: I'm solving MaxSAT, yes, but in many-valued logic.
The problem is (in my understanding) assert-soft accepts boolean constraints and I'm dealing with many-valued constraints.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: The site was rebuilt using wasm: https://www.philipzucker.com/z3-rise4fun/optimization.html